# How to configure iOS application icons in trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

I am trying to configure the iOS applications icons but adding this to the config.json doesn't work.

```
{
    "author": "myemail", 
    "config_version": "2", 
    "description": "My Extension Description",
    "icons": {
        "ios": {
            "57": "57px.png",
            "72": "72px.png",
            "114": "114px.png"
        }
    },...
```

All icons are in my src folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `icons` configuration must be inside a `modules` hash (see http://current-docs.trigger.io/modules/icons.html#config).

Also, see https://github.com/goodgravy/forge-spikes/tree/master/ios-icons for a stripped down example app which has a "lovely" magenta icon set.

Comment: The 512 px icons are displayed in iTunes, when installing IPAs, managing apps on a device - things like that.

Comment: Yeah thanks I figured it out.  I am just frustrated that my icons like horrid on the Kindle Fire carousel.  I guess I'll find out for certain once my app is available from the Amazon app store.

Comment: James, at that documentation page you show conflicting information about required icon sizes for Android. Is the full set 36/48/72px (as in the bullet list above the example) or 16/32/48px (as in the example)?  This is also true for the [1.4 docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/icons.html#config).